# MySQL, update multiple tables with one query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a function that updates three tables, but I use three queries to perform this. I wish to use a more convenient approach for good practice.

How can I update multiple tables in MySQL with a single query?

Comment: can you provide an example of the generated code?  Is there a common key between the tables?

Answer (score 505):

Take the case of two tables, `Books` and `Orders`. In case, we increase the number of books in a particular order with `Order.ID = 1002` in `Orders` table then we also need to reduce that the total number of books available in our stock by the same number in `Books` table.

```
UPDATE Books, Orders
SET Orders.Quantity = Orders.Quantity + 2,
    Books.InStock = Books.InStock - 2
WHERE
    Books.BookID = Orders.BookID
    AND Orders.OrderID = 1002;
```

Comment: If I want to include "LIMIT" to the SQL Query, do I have to say LIMIT 1 or LIMIT 2?

Comment: What is the advantage of doing this vs. a transaction? Thanks!

Comment: @paulkon, I assume that when using transactions, there is a lot of overhead involved since roll-backs have to be available if any procedure in the transaction fails.

Comment: General warning when using this query. The WHERE clause is evaluated separately for each table. The Books.BookID=Orders.BookID is very important, without it The Books table update would happen to all rows and not only for the row with the specified id. Some lessons are learned the hard way, this one was learned in the terrifing way.

Comment: What if I have a DAO layer. Is it better to use single statement for multiple update like this or create a transaction, using multiple DAOs? Which is a good practice? I ask, because AFAIU Single DAO should be responsible for single Entity. Here we have two entities : orders and books. Thanks!

Comment: @nheimann1 And that is exactly why I always recommend people use the ANSI "inner join" syntax. It's too easy to forget that condition and instead get a full Cartesian join.

Answer (score 99):

```
UPDATE t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
INNER JOIN t3 ON t2.t3_id = t3.id
SET t1.a = 'something',
    t2.b = 42,
    t3.c = t2.c
WHERE t1.a = 'blah';
```

To see what this is going to update, you can convert this into a select statement, e.g.:

```
SELECT t2.t1_id, t2.t3_id, t1.a, t2.b, t2.c AS t2_c, t3.c AS t3_c
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
INNER JOIN t3 ON t2.t3_id = t3.id
WHERE t1.a = 'blah';
```

An example using the same tables as the other answer:

```
SELECT Books.BookID, Orders.OrderID,
    Orders.Quantity AS CurrentQuantity,
    Orders.Quantity + 2 AS NewQuantity,
    Books.InStock AS CurrentStock,
    Books.InStock - 2 AS NewStock
FROM Books
INNER JOIN Orders ON Books.BookID = Orders.BookID
WHERE Orders.OrderID = 1002;

UPDATE Books
INNER JOIN Orders ON Books.BookID = Orders.BookID
SET Orders.Quantity = Orders.Quantity + 2,
    Books.InStock = Books.InStock - 2
WHERE Orders.OrderID = 1002;
```

EDIT:

Just for fun, let's add something a bit more interesting.

Let's say you have a table of `books` and a table of `authors`. Your `books` have an `author_id`. But when the database was originally created, no foreign key constraints were set up and later a bug in the front-end code caused some books to be added with invalid `author_id`s. As a DBA you don't want to have to go through all of these `books` to check what the `author_id` should be, so the decision is made that the data capturers will fix the `books` to point to the right `authors`. But there are too many books to go through each one and let's say you know that the ones that have an `author_id` that corresponds with an actual `author` are correct. It's just the ones that have nonexistent `author_id`s that are invalid. There is already an interface for the users to update the book details and the developers don't want to change that just for this problem. But the existing interface does an `INNER JOIN authors`, so all of the books with invalid authors are excluded.

What you can do is this: Insert a fake author record like "Unknown author". Then update the `author_id` of all the bad records to point to the Unknown author. Then the data capturers can search for all books with the author set to "Unknown author", look up the correct author and fix them.

How do you update all of the bad records to point to the Unknown author? Like this (assuming the Unknown author's `author_id` is 99999):

```
UPDATE books
LEFT OUTER JOIN authors ON books.author_id = authors.id
SET books.author_id = 99999
WHERE authors.id IS NULL;
```

The above will also update `books` that have a `NULL` `author_id` to the Unknown author. If you don't want that, of course you can add `AND books.author_id IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: > To see what this is going to update, you can convert this into a select statement

So if I understand this correctly, any row that is excluded as a result of `INNER JOIN` (= doesn't have a counterpart in the joined table) is not going to be updated, even if there isn't a where clause?

So I can just

```
UPDATE
  table1 INNER JOIN table2
  ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
SET ...
```

instead of
```
UPDATE table1
SET ...
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE table1_id = table.id)
```

Comment: @sisisisi yes. See this for an example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=18f8918233fce12c32c1d2e031e470a7

Answer (score 43):

You can also do this with one query too using a join like so:

```
UPDATE table1,table2 SET table1.col=a,table2.col2=b
WHERE items.id=month.id;
```

And then just send this one query, of course. You can read more about joins here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html. There's also a couple restrictions for ordering and limiting on multiple table updates you can read about here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html (just ctrl+f "join").

Comment: It's a bit generous to call that a "join" ;-)

Comment: Long ago, there were database engines that didn't even support `JOIN` in their SQL dialect, you just list multiple tables in `FROM`, and use `WHERE` to join them. Sometimes the term "equa-join" was used to refer to this idiom.

Answer (score 6):

That's usually what stored procedures are for: to implement several SQL statements in a sequence. Using rollbacks, you can ensure that they are treated as one unit of work, ie either they are all executed or none of them are, to keep data consistent.

Comment: where would i write the procedure? could you please provide an example?

Comment: Up-voted for explaining the necessity of atomicity - it is also important to realise that using stored procedures does not alone guarantee consistency, you still need to use transactions; likewise, transactions can be performed without using a stored procedure, provided they are performed over the same connection. In this case, the use of a multi-table update is even better.

Answer (score 4):

When you say multiple queries do you mean multiple SQL statements as in:

```
UPDATE table1 SET a=b WHERE c;
UPDATE table2 SET a=b WHERE d;
UPDATE table3 SET a=b WHERE e;
```

Or multiple query function calls as in:

```
mySqlQuery(UPDATE table1 SET a=b WHERE c;)
mySqlQuery(UPDATE table2 SET a=b WHERE d;)
mySqlQuery(UPDATE table3 SET a=b WHERE e;)
```

The former can all be done using a single mySqlQuery call if that is what you wanted to achieve, simply call the mySqlQuery function in the following manner:

```
mySqlQuery(UPDATE table1 SET a=b WHERE c; UPDATE table2 SET a=b WHERE d; UPDATE table3 SET a=b WHERE e;)
```

This will execute all three queries with one mySqlQuery() call.

Comment: mySqlQuery() is a custom function or in built function? I want to know more about this.

Comment: There is no significant difference between sending three queries individually or as a multiple query, except perhaps if your query function opens a new connection every time. From the point of view of server-side execution, it's the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Let's say I have `Table1` with primary key `_id` and a boolean column `doc_availability`; `Table2` with foreign key `_id` and DateTime column `last_update` and I want to change the availability of a document with `_id` 14 in `Table1` to 0 i.e unavailable and update `Table2` with the timestamp when the document was last updated. The following query would do the task:

```
UPDATE Table1, Table2 
SET doc_availability = 0, last_update = NOW() 
WHERE Table1._id = Table2._id AND Table1._id = 14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let id = req.params.id;
let pname = req.body.pname;
let catname = req.body.catname;
let scatname = req.body.scatname;
let price = req.body.price;
let available_qty = req.body.available_qty
```

`'UPDATE products,category,subcategoey   set category.name=?,subcategoey.name=?, products.name=?, products.price=?, products.available_qty=?  WHERE category.id= subcategoey.cid AND subcategoey.id = products.scid AND products.id=?',[catname,scatname,pname,price,available_qty,id],`

it works for me...