# updating two tables with a single query

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL, update multiple tables with one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query)

I'd like to know how to update two different tables with a single query, using MySql and C#.

Here is my query to read the data from the database.

```sql
string sql = @"SELECT clb.clube AS nome, clb.email AS email, clb.telefone AS 
telefone, usr.login AS login, usr.senha AS senha 
FROM clubes AS clb 
INNER JOIN usuarios AS usr ON usr.nome = clb.clube 
WHERE usr.login = @log";
```

Note that I get the data from `usr` and `clb`. Now, I'd like to update it. How can I do that?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

Answer (score 1):

You can join tables in the `UPDATE` statement:

```sql
UPDATE clubes AS clb INNER JOIN usuarios AS usr ON usr.nome = clb.clube
SET    clb.telefone = ...,
       usr.senha    = ...
WHERE  usr.login = @log
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, but something like this should work for you:

```
UPDATE clubes, usuarios
SET clubes.clube='SomeVal', 
   usuarios.senha='SomeVal'
WHERE usuarios.nome = clubes.clube
  AND usr.login = 'SomeVal';
```

Good luck.

Comment: I was unaware MySQL had this implemented, I stated in my Answer it was pulled from another post, I just forgot to put quotes around it. In my experience, normally these types of statements would fail. Even if you were targeting a view with the appropriate rules.

Comment: No worries, just wanted to make you aware it couldn't be done. I did not give you a down vote since your SQL was correct and would work, not sure who did that.  Good luck.

Comment: T'was my downvote, for "*I know you're using MySQL, but unfortunately the same rules apply*" (didn't leave a comment though, as yours already explained that).

Answer (score 0):

Try thsi please:

```
UPDATE clubes clb
INNER JOIN usuarios AS usr 
ON (usr.nome = clb.clube) 
SET youcolumns....
WHERE usr.login = @log
```

Comment: Actually just the login does not update... Maybe because i'm using the login field TO update and in WHERE clause... what you htink ?