# Duplicate Key Entry on Update query MySQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates

```
UPDATE Table1, Table2
SET Table1.Col1 = 1, Table1.Col2 = 2, Table2.Col1 = 3 
WHERE Table1.PKey = Table2.PKey AND Table1.PKey = 199
```

results in duplicate key entry

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '199-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

please help i've been scratching my head. I want this query to be optimal and fast since its used inside a loop that loops through a lot of rows and updates for each one. Dont want to split into 2 queries since then it will be 2 separate query calls per row.

Answer (score 2):

Your query above should work -- reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9417254/1073631

Guessing that you're trying to update a primary key (unique) column with a value that is already in another row in that same table --- hence the duplicate entry error.

Answer (score 1):

I think the primary key for your Table1 is on PKey AND Col1, i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE `Table1`
...
PRIMARY KEY (`PKey`,`Col1`)
```

The error about the duplicate entry **'199-1'** points in that direction.