# How can we update two different tables with single sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can we update two tables with single sql query?

Suppose I have two tables

```
1. Employee

empid  empname     salary
00001   Vijay      100000
00002   Alex       200000
00003   Jennifer   300000


2. Institute

regno    State        Country
123ab    Texas          USA
231nf    California     USA
```

So how can we update both tables lets say I want to update "salary" field of "empid" 00001 of "Employee" table and the "State" field of "regno" 123ab of Institute table.

Comment: You can't. `update` targets a single table only. use a transaction and two separate queries. the transaction will effective turn the two queries into a single one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query

Comment: Can we do that without using TRANSACTION?

Comment: I'll write it for money. If you show effort, I'll help for free ;)

Comment: Why using a single query to update two different tables which are related to each other? It needs two query and it is better to keep it that way.

Comment: @sshekhar i know with two queries its damn simple but can u help me with my question concerned ?

Comment: @RUJordan what effort ?

Answer (score 3):

1. if it's related data, you can probably can do a `JOIN`.
2. if it's not, you are probably looking not for 1 query, but 1 [*transaction*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html)
3. if you *still* need it to be 1 call, define a procedure

Comment: thanks for the information but mate can we use some other way to find the solution apart from Transaction and Procedures ?

Comment: @VijayChauhan By now you should be aware that there's no way to do it in a single SQL instruction... that's what transactions are for

Comment: Honestly, trying to avoid transactions or procedures, having unrelated data, and still insisting on a single query, smells a **lot** like asking for instructions on how to do an SQL-injection attack after having found a security flaw. It may not be it, but at the very least is see no _valid_ use for the requirements any other way.

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
query1;
query2;
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a stored procedure which updates Employee and then updates Institute so then your single query would be:

```
exec spUpdateEmployeeTableAndInstituteTable
```

Comment: Can we do that without using TRANSACTION?

Answer (score 0):

It actually can be done in one query:

```
UPDATE Employee e, Institute i
SET e.salary = <new salary>,
    i.state = <new state>
WHERE e.empid = '00001'
AND i.regno = '123ab'
```

Comment: U hav used JOIN operation but the tables are not related to each other so how can we have JOIN operation in that case ?

Comment: It just does a cross-product of the rows matching each condition.