# updating two table with one single insert-SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to make the following two queries to one single query?

```
update customers set customer_name = 'John'  where customer_id=1;

update purchases set state='Accepted'  where customer_id=1;
```

`customer` (table)

```
customer_id(PK)
customer_name
```

`purchases` (table)

```
customer_id(FK)
product
state
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL, update multiple tables with one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute them in a single transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
update customers set customer_name = 'John'  where customer_id=1;
update purchases set state='Accepted'  where customer_id=1;
COMMIT;
```

If something fail inside the transaction all changes are rolled back

Comment: Thanks man!Is there any other way like joining them and then updating?