# How to update a row which consists of three tables

Tags: sql

I have three tables:

**1. [Car]**

**2. [CarDetails]**

**3. [Car_Items]**

`[Car]` has columns `([Car_Name], [Car_Colour])`

`[CarDetails]` has columns `([ModelNo], [CarPrice])`

`[Car_Items]` has columns `([wheels], [Doors])`

---

I want to ask that if I want to update the data in these three tables where

```
Car.id = CarDetails.id = Car_Items.id
```

Can anyone please tell me a better way on how I could update the data in these tables?

Comment: Updating 3 tables takes 3 update statements.  Set values for the fields in one table, then move on to the next

Comment: put it into a procedure with transaction logic to allow rollback and write 3 updates.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL, update multiple tables with one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query)

Comment: You can't.

Please see

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005