# Multiple UPDATE table pdo php mqsql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I got the idea from answer of `Ifran` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query)  question. But i am getting this `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near`
Any suggestion is appreciated

```
$stmt9 = $dbh - > prepare("UPDATE student_info AS t1 ,
                                student_address AS t2 ,
                                student_course AS t3 ,
                                student_parentinfo AS t4,
                                student_references AS t5 ,
                                student_status AS t6 
                            SET t1.status = :status, 
                                t2.status = :status,
                                t3.status = :status,
                                t4.status = :status,
                                t5.status = :status,
                                t6.status = :status 
                            WHERE t1.pin = :pin,
                                t2.pin = :pin,
                                t3.pin = :pin,
                                t4.pin = :pin,
                                t5.pin = :pin,
                                t6.pin = :pin 
                            AND t1.status = :active,
                                t2.status = :active,
                                t3.status = :active,
                                t4.status = :active,
                                t5.status = :active,
                                t6.status = :active");

$stmt9 - > execute(array(':status' => $notactive, ':pin' => $pin, ':active' => $propertystatus));
```

Updated the code. Miss look some variables

Comment: You can't combine `WHERE` conditions with comma, only `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: Exactly what @Barmar said!

Comment: i didnt take that into consideration i was focusing on the tables before `WHERE` let me check that for a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all the commas in the WHERE clause to `AND`:

```
$stmt9 = $dbh - > prepare("UPDATE student_info AS t1 ,
                                student_address AS t2 ,
                                student_course AS t3 ,
                                student_parentinfo AS t4,
                                student_references AS t5 ,
                                student_status AS t6 
                            SET t1.status = :status, 
                                t2.status = :status,
                                t3.status = :status,
                                t4.status = :status,
                                t5.status = :status,
                                t6.status = :status 
                            WHERE t1.pin = :pin AND
                                t2.pin = :pin AND
                                t3.pin = :pin AND
                                t4.pin = :pin AND
                                t5.pin = :pin AND
                                t6.pin = :pin
                            AND t1.status = :active AND
                                t2.status = :active AND
                                t3.status = :active AND
                                t4.status = :active AND
                                t5.status = :active AND
                                t6.status = :active");
```

Also, in your `execute` call you have `:id`, which isn't used in the query, but no `:pin`, which is needed.