# How join more UPDATE query in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

Can anyone help me please? There are 2 queries. How join them to 1 query?

```
$sql1="UPDATE gallery 
       SET namesk='$_POST[namesk]', nameen='$_POST[nameen]', descriptionsk='$_POST[descriptionsk]', descriptionen='$_POST[descriptionen]', date='$_POST[date]', url1='$_POST[url1]' 
       WHERE namesk='$_GET[namesk]'";

$sql2="UPDATE photos 
       SET namesk_gallery='$_POST[namesk]'
       WHERE namesk_gallery='$_GET[namesk]'";
```

They works, but I would like to know, how to create one query.
Thanks very much.

Comment: You can't do it in one query, you could alternatively use `mysqli_multi_query` or create a stored procedure that encapsulates the various update statements within it.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query

Comment: @RamRaider, in the question that Calimero tagged, one query **is** used to do 2 tables, your statement is incorrect I'm afraid.

Comment: Just a note > using globals as $_POST[nameen] directly at your queries is really bad idea...

Comment: @Svetlio, I agree, some form of validation, even a `$var = isset($_POST['...'] ? "" : "";` would be good to use

Comment: I stand corrected - thanks @SamSwift웃 ~ always good to learn something new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easy to do (I use mysqli functionality for this):

```
$conn = mysqli_init();
$conn->real_connect("hostname", "username", "password", "dbname");

$query = "
    UPDATE gallery 
    SET namesk='{$_POST['namesk']}', nameen='{$_POST['nameen']}', descriptionsk='{$_POST['descriptionsk']}', descriptionen='{$_POST['descriptionen']}', date='{$_POST['date']}', url1='$_POST[url1]' 
    WHERE namesk='{$_GET['namesk']}';

    UPDATE photos 
    SET namesk_gallery='{$_POST['namesk']}'
    WHERE namesk_gallery='{$_GET['namesk']}';
";

$result = $conn->multi_query($query);
```

But make sure that after each of your queries you use the semi-colon (`;`) to separate them.

**Edits**

Added variable encapsulation for the `$_POST` and `$_GET` (don't know how you are using both at once...)

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9417254/4811060) gives a full *one query* version, I'd reproduce but that seems a waste when the answer is just there and with a very good explanation

Comment: In table "gallery" is 'namesk' type unique. In table "photos" is not 'namesk_gallery' unique, and it's there a many times. When I used one query with function JOIN, that cause, only one row in 'photos.namesk_gallery' was changed, not everyone with same name from $_GET['namesk']. ...All fields in the form are required, therefore I didn't use $var=isset... I use this code for changing informations about files in database from Form in admin environment. $_GET I got from button "edit" from another file.php.

Comment: `JOIN` is designed for `SELECT` queries, using `JOIN` in an `UPDATE` will cause errors and the query to fail, uniques don't really matter with `UPDATE` unless you are setting the field to be something...