# SQL make 2 update queries 1

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I got two update queries and I want to make one out of them but I can't figure out how? I have looked through some other examples here on Stack Overflow but I just can't get it to work.

query 1:

```
UPDATE `exercise_list` 
SET  `ex1`= `ex2`, `ex2`= `ex3`,`ex4` = NULL 
WHERE `day_ID`= 1 AND `user_ID`= 4
```

query 2:

```
UPDATE `training_results` 
SET `ex1`= `ex2`, `ex2`= `ex3`,`ex4` = NULL  
WHERE `day_ID`= 1 AND `user_ID`= 4
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL, update multiple tables with one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of achieving this:

1. Using a single mySqlQuery call, simply call the mySqlQuery function in the following manner:

   ```
   mySqlQuery(UPDATE exercise_list SET ex1= ex2, ex2= ex3,ex4 = NULL WHERE  
   day_ID= 1 AND user_ID= 4;   
   UPDATE training_results SET ex1= ex2, ex2= ex3,ex4 = NULL WHERE  
   day_ID= 1 AND user_ID= 4;)
   ```
2. Method 2:

   ```
   UPDATE exercise_list e_l ,training_results t_r SET  
   e_l.ex1=e_l.ex2, e_l.ex2=e_l.ex3,e_l.ex4=NULL,  
   t_r.ex1=t_r.ex2, t_r.ex2=t_r.ex3,t_r.ex4=NULL  
   WHERE e_l.day_ID = 1 AND e_l.user_ID = 4 AND  
   t_r.day_ID = 1 AND t_r.user_ID = 4;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Could be an inner join on the two tables

```
UPDATE exercise_list as a 
INNER JOIN training_results as b ON (a.day_ID = b.day_ID   AND a.user_ID = b.user_ID )
SET ex1= ex2, 
    ex2= ex3,
    ex4 = NULL
WHERE a.user_ID=4
AND a.day_ID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE A 
SET A.ex1 = A.ex2
, B.ex1 = B.ex2
, A.ex2 = A.ex3
, B.ex2 = B.ex3
, A.ex4 = NULL
, B.ex4 = NULL
FROM exercise_list A
JOIN training results B on  A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.day_id = 1 and A.user_id = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this:

```
UPDATE exercise_list as el, training_results as tr SET  
el.ex1=el.ex2,el.ex2=el.ex3, el.ex4=NULL, tr.ex1=tr.ex2, tr.ex2=tr.ex3, tr.ex4=NULL  
WHERE el.day_ID = 1 AND el.user_ID = 4 AND tr.day_ID = 1 AND tr.user_ID = 4;
```