# How can I update two different tables in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two tables like this:

```
// users
+----+--------+----------------------------+------------------+
| id |  name  |            email           | notification_num |
+----+--------+----------------------------+------------------+
| 1  | John   | John134@gmail.com          | 4                |
| 2  | Peter  | matrix_peter@ymail.com     | 2                |
| 3  | Jack   | jk_43m@gmail.com           | 6                |
+----+--------+----------------------------+------------------+

// notifications
+----+---------+---------+------+
| id | post_id | user_id | seen |
+----+---------+---------+------+
| 1  | 4325    | 2       | NULL |
| 2  | 8765    | 3       | NULL | 
| 3  | 5454    | 3       | 1    |
| 4  | 4346    | 2       | NULL |
| 5  | 3243    | 1       | 1    |
| 6  | 3246    | 2       | 1    |
| 7  | 3764    | 3       | 1    |
+----+---------+---------+------+
```

Ok, All I have is just a *user_id*. For example `:user_id = 2`, And then I want this output:

```
// users
+----+--------+----------------------------+------------------+
| id |  name  |            email           | notification_num |
+----+--------+----------------------------+------------------+
| 1  | John   | John134@gmail.com          | 4                |
| 2  | Peter  | matrix_peter@ymail.com     | 0                |
| 3  | Jack   | jk_43m@gmail.com           | 6                |
+----+--------+----------------------------+------------------+

// notifications
+----+---------+---------+------+
| id | post_id | user_id | seen |
+----+---------+---------+------+
| 1  | 4325    | 2       | 1    |
| 2  | 8765    | 3       | NULL | 
| 3  | 5454    | 3       | 1    |
| 4  | 4346    | 2       | 1    |
| 5  | 3243    | 1       | 1    |
| 6  | 3246    | 2       | 1    |
| 7  | 3764    | 3       | 1    |
+----+---------+---------+------+
```

As you see, I want to update `users.cotification_num` and set it to `0` *(for such an user)*, and I also want to update `notifications.seen` and set all rows to `1` *(for such an user)*. How can I do that?

---

I can do that by two different queries like this:

```
UPDATE users SET notification_num = 0 WHERE id = :user_id

UPDATE notifications SET seen = 1 WHERE seen is NULL and user_id = :user_id
```

But I want to know how can I do that by one query?

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a multiple-table `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE users u LEFT JOIN notifications n ON n.user_id = u.id
SET    u.notification_num = 0,
       n.seen = 1
WHERE  u.id = 2
```

Comment: Just one thing, Why `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @MartinAJ: If there are no records in the `notifications` table for that user, an inner join would fail to update the `users` table whereas this outer join will still do that.

Comment: Ah, what do you mean "outer join"? Are both `outer join` and `left join` the same?

Comment: @MartinAJ: LEFT JOIN is one of three types of outer join (RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN being the other two, although MySQL doesn't support the latter); in each case the keyword OUTER can be optionally inserted before the word JOIN, eg LEFT OUTER JOIN etc.  See Jeff Attwood's excellent article [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) for a good explanation of the difference.

Comment: got it, thx .. just you know, still I'm doubt to choose either `INNER JOIN` or  `LEFT JOIN`. You know, I have a trigger *(after insert)* on `notifications` table which increases `notification_num` column of `users` table. So in general, always there is row(s) in `notifications` table *(for that user)* if `users.notification_num` isn't `0`. Still do you think I need `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @MartinAJ: In that case no, you could also use INNER JOIN.  No harm in having an outer join though.

Answer (score 2):

You can join the tables together to `UPDATE` both in a single query:

```
UPDATE users, notifications
SET users.notification_num = 0
  ,  notification.seen = 1
WHERE users.id = notifications.user_id AND
      users.id = 2 AND
      notifications.seen is NULL
```

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query) for more information.  Another option would be to simply do 2 separate updates within a transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE users SET notification_num = 0 WHERE id = 2;
UPDATE notifications SET seen = 1 WHERE user_id = 2 AND notifications.seen is NULL;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: The IS NULL bit seems like it might be redundant.

Comment: @Strawberry well absolutely not ..! `... AND seen IS NULL` avoids to re-update the rows that have `seen=1` already.

Comment: @MartinAJ Updated per your comment, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @MartinAJ it makes no difference. MySQL won't update rows it doesn't need to

Comment: @Strawberry interesting, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

Note that my schema is very slightly different from yours - but it makes very little difference...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE users 
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name  VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,email VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,notification_num INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES
(1,'John','John134@gmail.com',4),
(2,'Peter','matrix_peter@ymail.com',2),
(3,'Jack','jk_43m@gmail.com',6);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notifications;

CREATE TABLE notifications 
(post_id INT NOT NULL
,user_id INT NOT NULL
,seen TINYINT DEFAULT 0
,PRIMARY KEY(post_id,user_id)
);

INSERT INTO notifications VALUES
(4325,2,0),
(8765,3,0),
(5454,3,1),
(4346,2,0),
(3243,1,1),
(3246,2,1),
(3764,3,1);

 SELECT * FROM notifications;
 +---------+---------+------+
 | post_id | user_id | seen |
 +---------+---------+------+
 |    3243 |       1 |    1 |
 |    3246 |       2 |    1 |
 |    3764 |       3 |    1 |
 |    4325 |       2 |    0 |
 |    4346 |       2 |    0 |
 |    5454 |       3 |    1 |
 |    8765 |       3 |    0 |
 +---------+---------+------+

 SELECT * FROM users;
 +----+-------+----------------------+------------------+
 | id | name  | email                | notification_num |
 +----+-------+----------------------+------------------+
 |  1 | John  | John134@gmail.com    |                4 |
 |  2 | Peter | matrix_peter@ymail.c |                2 |
 |  3 | Jack  | jk_43m@gmail.com     |                6 |
 +----+-------+----------------------+------------------+


UPDATE users u 
  JOIN notifications n 
    ON n.user_id = u.id
   SET u.notification_num = 0, n.seen = 1
 WHERE u.id = 2;

 SELECT * FROM users;
  +----+-------+----------------------+------------------+
  | id | name  | email                | notification_num |
  +----+-------+----------------------+------------------+
  |  1 | John  | John134@gmail.com    |                4 |
  |  2 | Peter | matrix_peter@ymail.c |                0 |
  |  3 | Jack  | jk_43m@gmail.com     |                6 |
  +----+-------+----------------------+------------------+

  SELECT * FROM notifications;
  +---------+---------+------+
  | post_id | user_id | seen |
  +---------+---------+------+
  |    3243 |       1 |    1 |
  |    3246 |       2 |    1 |
  |    3764 |       3 |    1 |
  |    4325 |       2 |    1 |
  |    4346 |       2 |    1 |
  |    5454 |       3 |    1 |
  |    8765 |       3 |    0 |
  +---------+---------+------+
```

Comment: I cannot see any difference between your schema and mine .. thank you anyway. upvote. Just onething, why not `LEFT JOIN` ?

Comment: There's no surrogate key on notifications and no null on `seen`. why left join? Seems like an extremely odd idea to me!

Comment: One thing, Why did you use `0` instead of `NULL`?

Comment: In this context, NULL means something like 'I don't know whether the message has been seen or not'. I can't see how that's useful. Surely it's better to say something like 'I assume that a message has not been seen, unless I know that it has'. 0 reflects that logic better.