# MySQL Query to update multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Quiz module in which I have two tables `quiz_question` and `quiz_options`. `quiz_question` is saving Questions 
and `quiz_option` saving options for particular questions.

> table structure for `quiz_option`:
>   id | question_id | text | is_correct
>
> table structure for  `quiz_question`
>   id | title | desctiption |

Where question_id is foreign key to id of `quiz_question`

I want to write a query to update quiz_question and all its corresponding quiz_options is a single query.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to update them in a single query? I don't think it's possible. You can use transactions if you want to make sure the updates are atomic.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple table update you can use foreign key connect two and more table with foreign key concept update parent table primary key to child table foreign key see link 
http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/mysql-foreign-key-example/.

```
table quiz_question PK (question_id)
table quiz_option FK (question_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the id of the question and Update them one by one as you cannot update two tables using a single query.

```
$ID_VALUE = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);
UPDATE quiz_option SET fields_name = 'value' WHERE question_id = $ID_VALUE;
UPDATE quiz_question SET fields_name = 'value' WHERE id = $ID_VALUE;
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527) Please do not teach bad coding habits.

Comment: He/she seems like a beginner to me so helped him/her with easy answer.

Comment: Alright.. My mistake once again.  :) I will careful next time

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query:

```
INSERT INTO quiz_question(title,description) VALUES ('test','test question'); 
INSERT INTO quiz_option(question_id,text,is_correct) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'test','0'),(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'test2','0'),(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'test3','0'),(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'test4','1')
```

Comment: This is Insert Query I need to update table.Anyways I think it is not possible with single Query.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
UPDATE  table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
SET     a.value = b.value
```

Comment: @ArditMeti the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) disagrees

Comment: @ArditMeti http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query