# How to update two tables in one mySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query in mysql.

```
UPDATE products A 
JOIN ea_pid B ON A.product_id = B.vpid
JOIN (SELECT product_id, sum(quantity) as quantity2 from ea_products 
GROUP BY product_id) D ON A.product_id = D.product_id
SET A.p_in_stock = (case when B.id = '1' THEN '30' when B.id = '0' THEN D.quantity2 end ) WHERE 1
```

I would like to update a second table with the same numbers. I tried to follow this solution [MySQL, update multiple tables with one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query) however always receive an error

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'A.product_id' in 'on clause'

This is the modified query I have so far which is producing this error:

```
UPDATE products_1 A, products_2 E 
JOIN ea_pid B ON A.product_id = B.vpid
JOIN (SELECT product_id, sum(quantity) as quantity2 from ea_products 
GROUP BY product_id) D ON A.product_id = D.product_id
SET A.p_in_stock = (case when B.id = '1' THEN '30' when B.id = '0' THEN D.quantity2 end ), E.p_in_stock = (case when B.id = '1' THEN '30' when B.id = '0' THEN D.quantity2 end ) WHERE 1
```

I would appreciate a lot any help how I could solve this

Comment: The error message means that the products table does not have a product_id field.

Comment: Thank you but this is quite not possible. The second table is a copy of the first one only with different numbers in p_in_stock field. I can run the query seperately for both tables but not together

Comment: You have no joining condition for the `E` table. So this is going to update every row in that table.

Comment: Don't mix a cross product with explicit `JOIN` clauses. Use `JOIN` for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix cross products with explicit `JOIN` clauses. I think it doesn't recognize `A` in the `ON` clause because of this. You also need a joining condition for `products_2`, otherwise it will update all rows with the same values.

```
UPDATE products_1 AS a
JOIN products_2 AS e ON a.product_id = e.product_id
JOIN ea_pid AS b ON a.product_id = b.vpid
JOIN (SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS quantity2
      FROM ea_products
      GROUP BY product_id) AS d
    ON a.product_id = d.product_id
SET a.p_in_stock = (CASE b.id
                    WHEN '1' THEN '30'
                    WHEN '0' THEN d.quantity2
                    END),
    e.p_in_stock = (CASE b.id
                    WHEN '1' THEN '30'
                    WHEN '0' THEN d.quantity2
                    END)
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar. This was it. The query is unfortunately quite slow but works like a charm.

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on all the columns being used in the joins.