# how to update multiple columns in multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

How can we update multiple columns in multiple tables in a single query?

I tried the below but no success.

---

[My tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0llD.jpg)

```
update Class c, School s
set c.Status='Absent', s.Status='Absent'
Where c.ID='&ID' and c.ID=s.ID;
```

---

Any clues are appreciable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL, update multiple tables with one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query)

Comment: there are lots of answers to this if you search, including the duplicate I've just suggested.

Comment: Your current query looks correct.  Have you actually tried running it?

Comment: Yes, but i am getting an error like 'ORA-00971: missing SET keyword'

Comment: You are missing a single quote in your query near c.Status='Absent, s.Status='Absent'

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. Apologies for that.

Comment: Did that fix your problem?

Comment: One gets ORA errors from *Oracle* not *MySQL*.

Comment: retracted my "marked as duplicate" vote, since OP had incorrectly tagged the question with MySQL instead of Oracle. A bit worrying, for someone whose profile gives their job title as "DB Engineer", that they cannot identify the DBMS they are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a direct update of multiple tables in Oracle.

You might be able to do an update of a view, like this:

```
update (
select c.status class_status, s.status school_status
from Class c, School s
Where c.ID='&ID' and c.ID=s.ID )
set class_status='Absent', school_status='Absent'
```

Oracle will only allow this if the join between the tables preserves keys - i.e. each row produced by the join directly maps to a single row in the source table(s) being updated.  I suspect that in this case that `School` is not key-preserved as each row in that table probably relates to more than one row in `Class`.  So you won't be able to do this in a single statement.

Oracle is far less tolerant of fuzzy relational thinking than other systems.