# Update multiple table with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables : `Pur_Entry and Pur_order`

```
Pur_entry => id, name, id_pur_order, is_deleted
Pur_order => id, date, is_deleted
```

I have to update '`is_delete`' in both tables at one action.

Is there any inner join method for these?

Comment: No, Update can only update columns in one table at a time, but you can send two updates to the database in one batch, in one transaction.

Comment: @CharlesBretana This is not true for MySQL.  MySQL supports updating multiple tables in a single statement.

Comment: @CharlesBretana so basically I have to use stored procedure right?

Comment: based on comment from @Siyual, I did some research. I was wrong. Check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html - second form "Multiple table Update syntax". You can ignore my previous comment.   Siyual, just curious, why not also provide the link to the docs in your comment?

Comment: @CharlesBretana Honestly, I was on mobile and didn't want to deal with copying links lol.  You're right, I should have, though.

Comment: Hah! no worries, I was just wondering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE pur_order a, pur_entry b SET a.is_deleted = 1, b.is_deleted = 1
WHERE b.id_pur_order = b.id AND a.id = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

This topic has been asked already before.
Have a look here: [MySQL, update multiple tables with one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query)

In your case, this should work:

```
UPDATE Pur_order, Pur_entry
   SET Pur_order.is_deleted = 1
      ,Pur_entry.is_deleted = 1
 WHERE Pur_entry.id_pur_order = Pur_order.id
   AND Pur_order.id = @YourDesiredUpdateId
;
```

Comment: but this will update all the fields, I have condition on pur_entry->id

Comment: @mauliksompura of course you have to specify the row you want to update. i just updated my answer. Variable YourDesiredUpdateId should hold the Id you want to update. or how do you specify the rows you want to update?

Comment: UPDATE Pur_order, Pur_entry
   SET Pur_order.is_deleted = 1
      ,Pur_entry.is_deleted = 1
 WHERE Pur_entry.id_pur_order = Pur_order.id
   AND Pur_entry.id = @id

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, flag it as such.