# MySQL, SQL - How to SELECT, UPDATE and REPLACE at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Before the question gets flagged, closed or anything I tried to look for an answer through the site and I always find one part of what I am looking for or what I am trying to do but never something concrete, I've tried to **SELECT** and **UPDATE** but never **SELECT**, **UPDATE** and **REPLACE**

So my issue is this:

I have a Wordpress database table `wp_posts` and another table named `wp_postmeta`,
`wp_post` have a row named `post_content` and `wp_postmeta` have a row called `meta_key`, I am trying to **SELECT**, **UPDATE** and **REPLACE** a string from `wp_post.post_content` without altering the other entries. In order to not modify the other entries I need to select from `wp_postmeta.meta_key` the entries that have the `meta_key` "*cities*".

So basically if I run

```
SELECT p.post_content FROM wp_post p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m ON p.id = m.post_id
WHERE p.post_content LIKE "%TEXT I NEED TO REPLACE%"
AND m.meta_key LIKE "%city%";
```

That will give me 600 entries from the 5000 that share the same text that I need to replace.

So if I just run

```
UPDATE wp_post SET post_content = REPLACE 
(post_content, 'TEXT I NEED TO REPLACE', 'NEW TEXT THAT I AM REPLACING');
```

That will change the 5000 entries and I don't want that, what I need is to replace the 600 entries from the **SELECT** query I ran before.

In summary I need a way to merge those 2 queries somehow in order to replace the post_content string of those 600 entries without affecting the other 4400 left, it is achievable?

I hope my issue is clear enough. Thanks again.

*(I am using Sequel Pro for this)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - UPDATE query based on SELECT Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query)

Comment: @jmoerdyk - My apologies, but how it is a duplicate regarding to what I am asking? I am not trying to update the whole row or entry, I am just trying to update and replace a string or a fragment from the value of that row.

Comment: Use the replace() function you already know when updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JOIN` and `WHERE` in an `UPDATE` query, just like a `SELECT` query, to filter the rows that get updated.

```
UPDATE wp_post AS p
JOIN wp_postmeta AS m ON p.id = m.post_id
SET p.post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'TEXT I NEED TO REPLACE', 'NEW TEXT THAT I AM REPLACING')
WHERE p.post_content LIKE "%TEXT I NEED TO REPLACE%"
AND m.meta_key LIKE "%city%";
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/32082037/495319 for another example of turning an `UPDATE` on more than one table into a `SELECT` (or vice versa).

Comment: This is the result I was expecting, thank you so much. I didn't know you could combine it like that. I am new into this.