# Error code 1052 on Updating two tables incorporating a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having issues updating two tables using a sub-query in the same query. This is part of a course project and it has to include both of those statements. I understand how sub-queries work and I am able to update the two tables at once, however it is still giving me this error when I try to incorporate the sub-query.

I have looked online and the only fix that I can find is to assign the fields an alias to avoid the ambiguous error. However I am not sure how to assign it in the update statement.

```
update item, shipment 
set item.price = 6.99,
    shipment.price = 6.99
where price like(
              select price
              from item
              join shipment on item.ship_id = shipment.ship_id
              where item_num = "android543");
```

I understand that this is ambiguous I am just not sure how to assign the values an alias.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish would all help.

Comment: `LIKE` is for character comparisons, not numbers. Numeric comparisons use numeric operators such as `=`, `<`, `>`, `<>`,`<=` and `>=`. `WHERE LastName LIKE 'Smi%'` is valid; `WHERE price LIKE 123` is not.

Comment: You cannot update two tables in a single SQL statement.

Comment: @NeerajAgarwal sure you can. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query

Comment: @Nick My bad I did not pay attention to the fact that this was for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables called `price` (`item.price` and `shipment.price`) and MySQL doesn't know which one you are referring to in:

```
where price like(
```

You need to be specific about which one you want e.g.

```
where item.price like(
```

Note that `like`, although it *might* work in this situation (e.g. `4.5 like 4.5` is true, but `4.5 like 4.50` is not), is intended for character type variables. A numeric operator such as `=` or possibly `IN` (if you expect multiple results from the subquery) is more appropriate in this case.

If I have understood your question correctly, you can probably more simply rewrite your query like this:

```
update item i
join shipment s on i.ship_id = s.ship_id
set i.price = 6.99,
    s.price = 6.99
where i.item_num = "android543"
```