# Select User id from one table and update in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table called `tbl_users` and `tbl_img_status`. I have column in `tbl_img_status` like below

```
id, user_id,status_text, scd_time,status,post_time
```

I am looking for run cron using PHP for publish post on time. So I have query like below

```
$results = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE tbl_img_status SET post_time=NOW(),status=1 WHERE status=0 AND scd_time<NOW()");
```

Now My issue is I also need to update tbl_users column called total_post. I want increase 1 in total_post of that user id which we have published with first query. I am new in PHP and MYSQL so not getting proper idea for do it. Let me know if someone can help me for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Triggers for that purpose.

This would update for a specific user if the status changed from 0 to 1

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_tbl_img_status_update
AFTER UPDATE
ON tbl_img_status  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.status <> NEW.status AND NEW.status = 1 THEN
        UPDATE tbl_users  SET total_post  = total_post +1 WHERE id = NEW.user_id;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

IF you don't want to change the Database, you can use a INNER JOIN with And update both table as one.

Your php will then look like:

```
$results = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE tbl_users tu INNER JOIN  tbl_img_status  tis ON tu.id = tis.user_id SET tis.post_time=NOW(), tis.status=1, tu.total_post = tu.total_post+1 WHERE tis.status=0 AND tis.scd_time<NOW();");
```

Comment: if you don't like the clean and simple mysql version i add also a version, that runs a query like before

Answer (score 2):

You can use one query to update two tables.
Try this query if that works.
I have got a hint from this. [MySQL, update multiple tables with one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query)

```
UPDATE tbl_users, tbl_img_status 
SET tbl_img_status.post_time=NOW(),
    tbl_img_status.status=1,
    tbl_users.total_post = tbl_users.total_post+1
WHERE
    tbl_users.id= tbl_img_status.user_id
    AND tbl_img_status.status=0 AND tbl_img_status.scd_time<NOW()
```

Comment: Riya please use that query in your mysqli_query method. Let me know.

Comment: Riya, I ve just checked from my phpmyadmin. I created two tables and added 1 for tbl_users and 2 for tbl_img_status containing status=0. And I run over query so the user was updated where has id equals to user_id of tbl_img_status So it runs cool! :)