# How to update two columns from another table without using loops

Tags: sql, node.js

```
const sqlu = 'update tempcsvuploaddss t, temp2 t2 
              set t.matchartist = t2.artist, 
                  t.matchtrack=t2.track  
              where  t2.IsFound = "Y"  
              and t.matchartist is null 
              and t.matchtrack is null ';
Query(sqlu);
```

Now result looks like this:

[image: 1]

only one record is updated in all rows
how to i can update all records

Comment: I don't see that you have joined both tables. So it's not a surprise that you get more or less a random result.

Comment: @fawad which dbms are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL, update multiple tables with one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query)

Comment: Screenshot of results tells exactly nothing without input data. Also do not use screenshot of data when it is not about visualization or data cannot be grabbed from UI without loss of information. Use text in tabular format.