# How can I write the SQL query to insert a record to a table by checking the foreign key?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm currently coding the **forgot password** option in **PHP**, and I'm having trouble with an SQL query.

My forgot password form has a field to enter the email address. When someone enters an email and hits the "Request New Password" button, it's supposed to create a `token` and a `token expiration time` and pass it to a database table. The `email` and the `token` columns are defined in **two** different tables (connected with a foreign key).

At first, I had all the columns defined in the `[users]` table, so storing the token details under the given email was easy to figure out. But I got stuck when I split the table into two. I can't figure out how to write the SQL query for that.

Here's what the two tables look like:

```
[users] => id, username, email, password   
[persistences] => id, user_id (foreign key), token, expires_at
```

This is what the `forgot_password()` function looked like when all the columns were defined in the `[users]` table:

```
public function forgot_password ($token, $email) 
{
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET token = :token, token_expire = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) WHERE email = :email";    
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);    
    $stmt->execute(['token' => $token, 'email' => $email]);    
    return true;    
}
```

How should the SQL query be changed to achieve the same goal, but when the columns are in separate tables?

Comment: i recommend to check https://stackoverflow.com/a/9417254/9240674. As stated, ensure to include `users.id = persistence.user_id` in WHERE clause.

Comment: Instead of `WHERE clause joins` use a typical join with the update, which is possible with MySQL and specify the join there instead.