# How to update values in two tables where one is usermeta MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have two tables and I need to make single SQL request which will update values in both of them.

Their releation is based on ID (1 table = evdb_users.ID / 2 table = evdb_usermeta.user_id)

For now I did some SQL query like this:

```
"UPDATE evdb_users
       INNER JOIN evdb_usermeta ON evdb_users.ID = evdb_usermeta.user_id AND evdb_usermeta.meta_key='phone_number'
       SET evdb_users.user_login='%s', evdb_users.user_email='%s', evdb_users.display_name='%s', evdb_usermeta.meta_value='%s'
       WHERE evdb_users.ID=%d"
```

Data in evdb_users (login/email/display name) - are updating, but nothing changes in usermeta (phone_number)

Please help me to figure out how it should be and how it must works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL, update multiple tables with one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no

Comment: Please help to figure you why "unforturtunatly no"

Comment: @Luuk thank you for your comment, generally it gave me a look how UPDATE should work but in special this case the answer to my question is the best option
Anyway thank you for your link. It will help me to understand this topic better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
UPDATE evdb_users
       INNER JOIN evdb_usermeta
         ON  evdb_users.ID = evdb_usermeta.user_id 
         AND evdb_usermeta.meta_key='phone_number'
       SET evdb_users.user_login='%s'
         , evdb_users.user_email='%s' 
         , evdb_users.display_name='%s' 
         , evdb_usermeta.meta_value='%s'
       WHERE evdb_users.ID=%d;
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! When I am trying to use it, i receive SQL error: "Alliance not unique (#1066)"

Comment: @AK  - which error ??

Comment: When I removed evdb_usermeta (from UPDATE evdb_users only left) = it works xD Have no idea why

Comment: my mistake :-( sorry

Comment: thank you a lot for your help! You helped me REALLY! I stuck with it for a long time, and now is everything works!!

Comment: Btw could you please write in your free time, why your answer worked? I am a new in this stuff and I really have no idea why its working in such way